# Is the Assets API blocking?

Tags: meteor

The Meteor docs state for the [assets API](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets):

> `asyncCallback` *Function*
>   Optional callback, which is called asynchronously with the error or result after the function is complete. If not provided, the function runs synchronously.

Much of Meteor functions can be used in a synchronous style despite being asynchronously ran.

So is the Assets API blocking synchronous or Fibers synchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses `fs` which is io blocking, with fibers to make it synchronous:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/19080bd53de3e0954e17914410bcf3fa0fead9c8/tools/server/boot.js#L189

So its 'fibers blocking', where you can use `this.unblock()` in a method to create a new fiber if the current one is being blocked.